# Getting Error when trying to set a string equal to a part of an NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to set an NSString to a token from the JSON data I get back when I make a post request. The error I'm getting is a No visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector 'appName'. I'm initializing userAuthToken in AppDelegate so it acts like a global variable since I want to use userAuthToken in multiple classes.

**Line of Code:**

```
[[self appName] userAuthToken:jsonData[@"token"]];
```

**Method appName (it's in the same file as the code above):**

```
+ (AppDelegate*)appName
{
    return (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

Comment: Why is a function returning your app delegate called "appName?"  That's not very good design.

Comment: To get the app name try: [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]

Comment: Also for sharing something try implementing the singleton pattern. e.g. +sharedInstance.

Comment: The problem is that you're attempting to invoke a class method using an instance pointer.  Do `[ViewController appName]` instead (assuming that "ViewController" is the name of your class).

Comment: @MitchellCurrie - You gave two bad pieces of advice.  Too bad one can't downvote comments.  (Though I agree with Nicholas Hart that the function should not be called "appName" -- "appDelegate" is more appropriate.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I do in all of my projects now. Create a new file called "Definitions.h"

in your .pch file inside your project:

```
#import "Definitions.h"
```

Inside Definitions.h

```
//Definitions.h
#define AppDelegate() (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]
```

Now, anywhere in your code, you can do this:

```
AppDelegate *del = AppDelegate();
[del userAuthToken:jsonData[@"token"];
```